# Why do I need a temporary value for the columns in the 2D Fourier Transform (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dft

Here is the matlab code for a 2D discrete Fourier Transform. This code was transcribed from:

*Scilab Textbook Companion for Digital Image Processing
by S. Jayaraman, S. Esakkirajan And T. Veerakumar*.

I am not really certain what is going on during the second for loop, and why we have to use a temporary value for f_2.

What is happening during this stage of the script?

Thank you.

```
function [ftransformed2d]= dft2d(f)    

[rows,cols]=size(f); 

for k=1:cols 

    f_1(:,k)=exp(-2*1j*pi*(0:nROWs-1)'*(0:rows-1)/rows)*f(:,k);
end


for J=1:rows 
    f_2_a=exp(-2*1j*pi*(0:nCOLs-1)'*(0:nCOLs-1)/cols)*(f_1(J,:)).';
    f_2(J,:)=f_2_a.';   
end

ftransformed2d = circshift(f_2,floor(size(f_2)/2));
end
```

Comment: It appears that code has never been compile-tested.  Beyond the obvious typos, there are clear and trivial performance issues, such as growing a matrix inside a loop.

Comment: I didn't write this code, I am just using it to get a better understanding of the technique. How can I make this code more rubust, as you suggest? It runs and works though.

Comment: The MATLAB editor should be giving you some tips, like preallocate your matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is embarrassing that I left out something so obvious, but the code runs so much faster now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop performs an FFT on each column, and the second loop performs an FFT on each row. As concerns the second loop,

```
 f_2_a=exp(-2*1j*pi*(0:cols-1)'*(0:cols-1)/cols)*(f_1(J,:)).';
 f_2(J,:)=f_2_a.';
```

the use of `f_2_a` is certainly not necessary but may have been included for ease of reading. It could have been written instead as

```
 f_2(J,:) = ( exp(-2*1j*pi*(0:cols-1)'*(0:cols-1)/cols)*(f_1(J,:)).' ).';
```